# Stopping h2 embedded db

Tags: spring, h2

currently i am using the following configuration in my spring context for h2 embedded db:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource">
            <property name="driverClass" value="org.h2.Driver" />
            <property name="url"
                value="jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;TRACE_LEVEL_SYSTEM_OUT=2" />
        <property name="username" value="sa" />
        <property name="password" value="" />                 
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

I am able to start and stop the db when tomcat is started or stopped. 
I want to restart my h2 embedded DB when i redeploy my app.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1` will ensure the database is kept even when all connections are closed. If you remove this option, then the data is lost as soon as the last connection is closed.

Comment: I have made DB_CLOSE_DELAY=10 . As data is getting lost when the connection is closed, is there a way to take backup of that data automatically.

Comment: You are currently using the in-memory mode. If you don't want to lose the data, why don't you use the persisted mode?